# Why am I missing some of the TFS work functionality

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

My team are currently experimenting with TFS, and have started using the Agile template to manage the team (We're currently using Update 3 On Premises). However, the videos and rescources I'm looking at have work item categories that aren't available, such as epics and features.

We only have *Product Backlog Items* and *Bugs*.

Is there something I need to tick somewhere for this to happen or is this because we have an old version? I can't find in the documentation that shows that these features have been introduced in subsequent versions to what we have.

**Can anyone shed some light as to how we get features and epics into our system?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Epics are only in Visual Studio Online at the moment. Features have been in TFS 2013 since RTM, so if you're not seeing them it could be an issue with your process template or your team configuration.

You might need to perform this process in order to update the process template:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff432837(v=vs.120).aspx